# How to do this in Scala way: get the first element from Option[Seq[String]]

Tags: scala

How to do this in Scala way: return the first element as `Some[String]` from `Option[Seq[String]]`, if it's `Some[Seq[String]]` and has least one string, otherwise return `None`

Comment: In your application, what is the difference between `None` and an empty `Seq()`?  If there isn't one, consider ditching the `Option` altogether.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`headOption` does what you want on the `Seq`, and `flatMap` on the `Option` can do the rest:

```
def first[A](maybe: Option[Seq[A]]): Option[A] = maybe.flatMap(_.headOption)
```

This is essentially the same as the following, but more concise and idiomatic:

```
def first[A](maybe: Option[Seq[A]]): Option[A] = maybe match {
  case Some(xs) => xs.headOption
  case None => None
}
```

Note that both versions are a little more generic than what you requested, but you can drop the type parameter and replace `A` with `String` if you only want it to work with strings.

Comment: Cool. Didn't know headOption.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getHead(strings: Option[Seq[String]]): Option[String] = {
  strings.collectFirst {
      case seq if seq.nonEmpty => seq.head
    }
}
```